# sum of time based on flag from multiple rows SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having tough time executing one of the query. I need to find the ignition time based on the flag from same table. table is like below,

```
UnitId      eventtime               ign
----------- ----------------------- -----
356         2011-05-04 10:41:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 10:42:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 10:43:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 10:45:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 10:47:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 10:48:00.000 0
356         2011-05-04 11:14:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 11:14:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 11:15:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 11:15:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 11:15:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 11:16:00.000 0
356         2011-05-04 11:16:00.000 0
356         2011-05-04 11:16:00.000 0
356         2011-05-04 14:49:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 14:50:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 14:50:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 14:51:00.000 1
356         2011-05-04 14:52:00.000 0
356         2011-05-04 14:52:00.000 0
356         2011-05-04 20:52:00.000 0
```

Here, The Ign flag will determine the ignition_on and iginition_off time.
So above table we can have the ignition pair of

```
2011-05-04 10:41:00.000 - 2011-05-04 10:48:00.000
2011-05-04 11:14:00.000 - 2011-05-04 11:16:00.000
2011-05-04 14:49:00.000 - 2011-05-04 14:52:00.000
```

So from looking at the above pair I can say that my unit runs for 7 + 2 + 3 = 12 minutes. I DONT WANT THE ABOVE PAIRS IN MY RESULT, ITS FOR EXAMPLE ONLY. MY AIM HERE IS TO GET THIS RESULT OF 12 MINUTES.

How can I achieve it using single query, right now I am using the CURSOR loop but this thing takes much more time for multiple days and multiple units. Is there anyway by which I can achieve it without the CURSOR?

Comment: No other columns in your table? No Primary Key?

Comment: I have identity column set as a PK. I have not shown it above ;) But you can consider one

Comment: What if the last row's `ign` is `1`? What time should be considered as the 'Until' time then?

Comment: If the last row's ign is 1 then we have to ignore it, we have to find the pairs only. if current unit status is ON then we have to wait until its turn it off to calculate the minutes. I think this is the easy solution and will not increase my problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there was an additional criterion for us to distinguish contiguous sequences of events with identical `ign` values from one another, we could take from each sequence with `ign=1` its earliest event and link it with the earliest event of the corresponding `ign=0` sequence.

It is possible to add such a criterion, as you will see below. I'm going to post the solution first, then explain how it works.

First, the setup:

```
DECLARE @atable TABLE (
  Id int IDENTITY,
  UnitId int,
  eventtime datetime,
  ign bit
);
INSERT INTO @atable (UnitId, eventtime, ign)
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 10:41:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 10:42:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 10:43:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 10:45:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 10:47:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 10:48:00.000', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 11:14:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 11:14:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 11:15:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 11:15:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 11:15:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 11:16:00.000', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 11:16:00.000', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 11:16:00.000', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 14:49:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 14:50:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 14:50:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 14:51:00.000', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 14:52:00.000', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 14:52:00.000', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 356, '2011-05-04 20:52:00.000', 0;
```

And now the query:

```
WITH
marked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    Grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UnitId ORDER BY eventtime) -
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UnitId, ign ORDER BY eventtime)
  FROM @atable
),
ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    seqRank = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UnitId, ign ORDER BY Grp),
    eventRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UnitId, ign, Grp ORDER BY eventtime)
  FROM marked
),
final AS (
  SELECT
    s.UnitId,
    EventStart = s.eventtime,
    EventEnd   = e.eventtime
  FROM ranked s
    INNER JOIN ranked e ON s.UnitId = e.UnitId AND s.seqRank = e.seqRank
  WHERE s.ign = 1
    AND e.ign = 0
    AND s.eventRank = 1
    AND e.eventRank = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM final
ORDER BY
  UnitId,
  EventStart
```

This is how it works.

The `marked` common table expression (CTE) provides us with the additional criterion I was talking about at the beginning. The result set it produces looks like this:

```
Id  UnitId  eventtime                ign  Grp
--  ------  -----------------------  ---  ---
1   356     2011-05-04 10:41:00.000  1    0
2   356     2011-05-04 10:42:00.000  1    0
3   356     2011-05-04 10:43:00.000  1    0
4   356     2011-05-04 10:45:00.000  1    0
5   356     2011-05-04 10:47:00.000  1    0
6   356     2011-05-04 10:48:00.000  0    5
7   356     2011-05-04 11:14:00.000  1    1
8   356     2011-05-04 11:14:00.000  1    1
9   356     2011-05-04 11:15:00.000  1    1
10  356     2011-05-04 11:15:00.000  1    1
11  356     2011-05-04 11:15:00.000  1    1
12  356     2011-05-04 11:16:00.000  0    10
13  356     2011-05-04 11:16:00.000  0    10
14  356     2011-05-04 11:16:00.000  0    10
15  356     2011-05-04 14:49:00.000  1    4
16  356     2011-05-04 14:50:00.000  1    4
17  356     2011-05-04 14:50:00.000  1    4
18  356     2011-05-04 14:51:00.000  1    4
19  356     2011-05-04 14:52:00.000  0    14
20  356     2011-05-04 14:52:00.000  0    14
21  356     2011-05-04 20:52:00.000  0    14
```

You can see for yourself how every sequence of events with identical `ign` can now be easily distinguished from the others by its own key of `(UnitId, ign, Grp)`. So now we can rank every sequence as well as every event within a sequence, which is what the `ranked` CTE does. It produces the following result set:

```
Id  UnitId  eventtime                ign  Grp  seqRank  eventRank
--  ------  -----------------------  ---  ---  -------  ---------
1   356     2011-05-04 10:41:00.000  1    0    1        1
2   356     2011-05-04 10:42:00.000  1    0    1        2
3   356     2011-05-04 10:43:00.000  1    0    1        3
4   356     2011-05-04 10:45:00.000  1    0    1        4
5   356     2011-05-04 10:47:00.000  1    0    1        5
6   356     2011-05-04 10:48:00.000  0    5    1        1
7   356     2011-05-04 11:14:00.000  1    1    2        1
8   356     2011-05-04 11:14:00.000  1    1    2        2
9   356     2011-05-04 11:15:00.000  1    1    2        3
10  356     2011-05-04 11:15:00.000  1    1    2        4
11  356     2011-05-04 11:15:00.000  1    1    2        5
12  356     2011-05-04 11:16:00.000  0    10   2        1
13  356     2011-05-04 11:16:00.000  0    10   2        2
14  356     2011-05-04 11:16:00.000  0    10   2        3
15  356     2011-05-04 14:49:00.000  1    4    3        1
16  356     2011-05-04 14:50:00.000  1    4    3        2
17  356     2011-05-04 14:50:00.000  1    4    3        3
18  356     2011-05-04 14:51:00.000  1    4    3        4
19  356     2011-05-04 14:52:00.000  0    14   3        1
20  356     2011-05-04 14:52:00.000  0    14   3        2
21  356     2011-05-04 20:52:00.000  0    14   3        3
```

You can see that an `ign=1` sequence can now be matched with an `ign=0` sequence with the help of `seqRank`. And picking only the earliest event from every sequence (filtering by `eventRank=1`) we'll get start and end times of all the `ign=1` sequences. And so the result of the `final` CTE is:

```
UnitId  EventStart               EventEnd
------  -----------------------  -----------------------
356     2011-05-04 10:41:00.000  2011-05-04 10:48:00.000
356     2011-05-04 11:14:00.000  2011-05-04 11:16:00.000
356     2011-05-04 14:49:00.000  2011-05-04 14:52:00.000
```

Obviously, if the last `ign=1` sequence isn't followed by an `ign=0` event, it will not be shown in the final results, because the last `ign=1` sequence will have no matching `ign=0` sequence, using the above approach.

There's one possible case when this query will not work as it is. It's when the event list starts with an `ign=0` event instead of `ign=1`. If that is actually possible, you could simply add the following filter to the `ranked` CTE:

```
WHERE NOT (ign = 0 AND Grp = 0)
-- Alternatively: WHERE ign <> 0 OR Grp <> 0
```

It takes advantage of the fact that the first value of `Grp` will always be `0`. So, if `0` is assigned to events with `ign=0`, those events should be excluded.

---

Useful reading:

- [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)
- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

  - [DENSE_RANK (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)
  - [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: I just need this query one more time today and your help saves me a lot of time again. Thank you very much

Comment: Hey, that was really nice of you to come back to just tell me that, thanks! (Even more so since I was able to spot and old typo, too.)

Comment: Can you help me in modifying the above query to also calculate the ignition off time? I have been trying but nothing is working for me

Comment: @user867198: Possibly the following changes to the `final` CTE will suffice: #1) swap the table aliases between `EventStart` and `EventEnd` (`s` <-> `e`, in the SELECT clause only), #2) change `s.seqRank = e.seqRank` to `s.seqRank = e.seqRank + 1` (in the join condition). If that doesn't help, please consider posting a new question.

Answer (score 2):

It's getting late, so rather than write out all the code this time I'm just gonna summarize how to do this:

Join the table to itself where one of the join conditions for the right hand side is a correlated sub query that selects the top 1 min(eventtime) from the table that is > the current row from the left hand side. Then use a where clause to filter this to rows where the ign column on the left side is <> to the ign column on the right side. That gets you your changes. Use a similar technique to join back to the table a third time, and you'll have records that have both a start time and end time that you can use with date functions to get your minute values.

Answer (score 0):

You can join your own table based on row_number()

```
select t1.RowNo as t1Row, t2.RowNo as t2Row, t1.StarTime, t2.EndTime as EndTime, cast(t2.EndTime - t1.StarTime as time) as Duration, t1.ign as IgnPeriod
from (select eventtime as StarTime, ign, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by eventtime) as RowNo from UnitTable)  as t1
inner join (select * from (select eventtime as EndTime, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by eventtime) as RowNo from UnitTable) as t_inner) t2 on t1.RowNo + 1 = t2.RowNo
```

You can then sum the duration for the ign=1 periods:

```
select cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,duration)),0) as time) from 
(select cast(t2.EndTime - t1.StarTime as time) as Duration, t1.ign as IgnPeriod
from (select eventtime as StarTime, ign, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by eventtime) as RowNo from UnitTable)  as t1
inner join (select * from (select eventtime as EndTime, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by eventtime) as RowNo from UnitTable) as t_inner) t2 on t1.RowNo + 1 = t2.RowNo
) t_outer
where t_outer.IgnPeriod = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, Its not giving me the right answer.
You have written the t1.RowNo +1 = t2.RowNo condition which i think is leading to the wrong result.

Comment: `t1.RowNo +1 = t2.RowNo` is to map one StartTime in t1 to the next EndTime in t2. In my testtable with your sample data I got exactly 12 minutes.